# What does the following warning mean?

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

What does the following warning mean and how can I fix its cause?

```
Warning: Unimplemented primitive used:removeEventListener
```

in

```
[@bs.val]
external addEventListener: (string, unit => unit) => unit = "addEventListener";
external removeEventListener: (string, unit => unit) => unit =
  "removeEventListener";

...

React.useEffect(() => {
  let handler = () => dispatch(ToggleMenu(false));
  addEventListener("popstate", handler);
  Some(() => removeEventListener("popstate", handler));
});
```

Comment: `external`s without attributes are assumed to be compiler-provided primitives. In a future release of BuckleScript I believe you'll be able to define these primitives yourself in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `[@bs.val]` at the front of `removeEventListener` when declaring the binding.

```
[@bs.val]
external addEventListener: (string, unit => unit) => unit = "addEventListener";
[@bs.val]
external removeEventListener: (string, unit => unit) => unit =
  "removeEventListener";
```

Sometimes it's difficult to see this because the linter is always moving lines around ;)

Source: I've also ran into this minutes ago.